# How to get this sql table from other table?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to have something like:

```
id Name    value
--------------------
1  sex        m 
2  age        12
3  weight    200
4  height    200
5  rx         34

from a known table:

sex age weight height rx
--------------------------
m   12    200  200    34
```

If I do:

```
Select
    [id] = ORDINAL_POSITION,
    [Name] = COLUMN_NAME
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where TABLE_NAME = 'known'
```

I get:

```
   id Name    
    -----------
    1  sex     
    2  age     
    3  weight  
    4  height  
    5  rx
```

how to changethe query to get:

```
   id Name    value
    --------------------
    1  sex        m 
    2  age        12
    3  weight    200
    4  height    200
    5  rx         34
```

If they were 2 rows:

```
sex age weight height rx
--------------------------
m   12    200  200    34
f   34    245  111    67


id Name    value
--------------------
1  sex        m 
2  age        12
3  weight    200
4  height    200
5  rx         34
6  sex        f 
7  age        34
8  weight    240
9  height    111
10 rx         67
```

**-----------------EDIT--------------------**

Thanks for your answers, but I am wondering if this can be possible intead of getting

```
  id  value
    -------------------
    1  m
    2  12
    3  200
    4  200
    5  34

    from:

    sex age weight height rx
    --------------------------
    m   12    200  200    34
```

using

```
 Select
[id] = ORDINAL_POSITION,
[Value] ...
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'known'
```

Comment: What would the result be if you have more than one row in the table?

Comment: What is the problem with the solutions provided? You don't **have** to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS to get the result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're going to run into whatever method you choose is that all data in a particular column must be of the same type. In your case you have sex, which is a character, and a bunch of numbers (probably integers). This stops you being able to do this neatly as you cant use UNPIVOT. However there is always a way...

Given this setup code:

```
CREATE TABLE test(sex char(1), age int, weight int, height int, rx int)
INSERT INTO test
SELECT 'm', 12 , 200, 200, 34
union select 'f',34,245,111,67
```

You can do this, which is just a small addition to your query:

```
Select
[id] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY isc.ORDINAL_POSITION),
[Name] = COLUMN_NAME,
[Value] = CASE LOWER(COLUMN_NAME)
            WHEN 'sex' THEN CAST(d.sex AS VARCHAR(20))
            WHEN 'age' then CAST(d.age AS VARCHAR(20))
            WHEN 'weight' THEN CAST(d.weight AS VARCHAR(20))
            WHEN 'height' THEN CAST(d.height AS VARCHAR(20))
            WHEN 'rx' THEN CAST(d.rx AS VARCHAR(20))
        END
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS isc
CROSS JOIN dbo.test d
where TABLE_NAME = 'test'
```

Output:

```
1   sex m
2   sex f
3   age 12
4   age 34
5   weight  200
6   weight  245
7   height  200
8   height  111
9   rx  34
10  rx  67
```

You''ll notice this output is in a slightly different order to your own. This is because you have not described any key on your "known" table. If you did have a key on that table, you simply change this line:

```
[id] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY isc.ORDINAL_POSITION),
```

to

```
[id] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.yourKeyField, isc.ORDINAL_POSITION),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with PIVOT/UNPIVOT (see Books Online).

Comment: Is there a way to just add something to the query that I already have?

Comment: Why do you want this solution? I haven't seen it before. If you don't know count of columns you can use UNPIVOT with dynamic SQL.

Comment: The problem with unpivot, is that all the columns need to be the same type, as im guessing the sex column is character based and the others are numeric, it doesnt work. You get something like `The type of column "age" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
declare @T table
(
  sex char(1),
  age int,
  weight int,
  height int,
  rx int
)

insert into @T values
('m',   12,    200,  200,    34),
('f',   34,    245,  111,    67)

select row_number() over(order by (select 1)) as ID,
       T2.X.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(128)') as Name,
       T2.X.value('.', 'varchar(10)') as Value
from (select *
      from @T 
      for xml path(''), type
     ) as T1(X)
  cross apply T1.X.nodes('/*') as T2(X)
```

This part `order by (select 1)` makes the assignment of ID's somewhat unpredictable. If you had a primary key `(ID int identity)` or a `datetime` to use in order by you could change that to `order by ID` instead.